# Number of distinct 4-factorisation of an integer

Tags: combinatorics

I have an integer 264600 = $2^3 \times 3^3 \times 5^2 \times 7^2$. I want to count the number of distinct 4-tuples (a,b,c,d) such that abcd = 264600 and a,b,c,d are nonnegative integers. How do I do that?

Would be even better to find a formula for $ F(M,k) $ which is the number of distinct k-tuples such that the product in the k-tuple is M (assume that we know the prime decomposition of M), not counting equivalent tuples (two tuples are equivalent if one is a permutation of another).

I tried two approaches:

1. Find a relationship between $ F(N,k) $ and $ F(M \times p^a,k) $ for a prime p.
2. Find the number of nonnegative integral solutions to $ x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 3 $ and $ y_{1} + y_{2} + y_{3} + y_{4} = 2 $ and try to find a way to get all the tuples.

I got stuck with both approaches.

Comment: See (https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48206)

Comment: This is not an easy problem. The best I can do is direct you to the relevant link: [Multiplicative Partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) and to give you a handy search term that may help: "factorisatio numerorum".

Comment: I found $1812$ quadruples but I do not understand well you question. For instance $14 ,\;     21,\;      25  ,\;    36$ is one of the solutions, but it can't be found directly from the factorization of $264600=2^3 \times 3^3 \times 5^2 \times 7^2$ in the way you describe your second approach

Answer (score 0):

By a stars-and-bars argument, there are $m+k-1\choose k$ to distribute $k$ balls to $m$ bins. Here, we want four bins (one per factor), and (independently per prime) have as many balls as the exponent of the prime. Hence the answer to your specific question is
$${4+3-1\choose 3}{4+3-1\choose 3}{4+2-1\choose 2}{4+2-1\choose 2}=20\cdot 20\cdot10\cdot 10 =40000$$

Comment: Doesn't this count (8)(27)(25)(49) and (27)(8)(25)(49) as distinct?